# How to remove the blinking caret on focus in css?

Tags: html, forms, focus, textfield, caret

I am working on a website in which I want to remove the blinking caret when a textbox gains focus.

[image]

The snippets of HTML codes which I have used in order to make the input search form are:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-searchicon">
   <input class="form-control search_radius mb-4" type="text">
   <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true "></span>
</div>
<div class="input-searchradius">
   <input class="form-control search_radius mb-4" type="text" placeholder="search radius">
   <span class="fa fa-globe globe" aria-hidden="true "></span>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the code above so that on focus blinking caret is not visible. I tried with the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
input-searchicon:focus
{
outline:none;
}
```

Comment: input:focus {
    outline: none;
} try this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give the `input` a transparent color and a `text-shadow` to display the text.

```css
input{
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0 0 0 #2196f3;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-searchicon">
   <input class="form-control search_radius mb-4 input-searchicon" type="text">
   <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true "></span>
</div>
<div class="input-searchradius">
   <input class="form-control search_radius mb-4" type="text" placeholder="search radius">
   <span class="fa fa-globe globe" aria-hidden="true "></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked but i am wondering what is the purpose of using `input-searchicon:focus
{
outline:none;
}` ? It is working by using `input { color:transparent;}`

Comment: @user5447339 I just added some of your code and forgot to remove it. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Now if I select the dates from the [website](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/), it doesn't get selected. Is there any way we can fix that ?

Comment: @user5447339 What dates?

Comment: @user5447339 Add `text-shadow: 0 0 0 #2196f3`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I am wondering what is the purpose of using three zeros before the number #2196f3 ?

Comment: @user5447339 Read this on the `text-shadow` CSS property: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp

Comment: The three zeroes were the h-shadow, v-shadow, and blur-radius values, respectively.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. I have one more quick regarding the [website](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/). After selecting the dates, its going all the way towards the left. Is there any way we can push towards the center ?

Comment: @user5447339 You can use `text-align: center`.

Comment: yeah, I have to use `text-align: center` but where i have to use it ?

Comment: @user5447339 Set that style on your `input`: `<input style="text-align: center;"/>`.

Answer (score 9):

In CSS 3 you can use [caret-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color) :

```css
caret-color: transparent
```